A practical way to understand subgaussian parameter
I am currently assuming that the random variable $X$ I am working with is subgaussian with parameter $\sigma^2$. I have simulated data, but I would like to know how to use the generated data to compute or estimate this parameter.
This random variable $X$ was not directly generated by me, so I am not certain of its exact distribution or whether it is bounded. $X$ is a complex function of the random variables I generated, so although I have realizations of $X$, its distribution is unknown.
I understand that the subgaussian parameter provides an upper bound for the variance. May I get some advise on how a practitioner might estimate this subgaussian parameter?

Subgaussianity concerns asymptotic properties of the tails, about which almost nothing can be said based on data alone.  Please, then, tell us what assumptions you are making about the distribution of $X.$
